# Add equation number to tabular that contains text + vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: tables, equations, numbering, text

I have the following code that makes a table, and I would like to add an equation number to it (so I can refer to it in the text by number). Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | c | c |}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Signaler strategy}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Chooser strategy} & TFT & ALLD \\ \hline
    TFT (Accept) & $\frac{bw_{c}w_{s}-c}{1-(w_{c}w_{s})^2},\frac{b-cw_{c}w_{s}}{1-(w_{c}w_{s})^2}$ & $-c,b$ \\ \hline
    ALLD (Reject) & 0,0 &  0,0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just enclose it an `equation` environment:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:tab}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | c | c |}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Signaler strategy}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Chooser strategy} & TFT & ALLD \\ \hline
    TFT (Accept) & $\frac{bw_{c}w_{s}-c}{1-(w_{c}w_{s})^2},\frac{b-cw_{c}w_{s}}{1-(w_{c}w_{s})^2}$ & $-c,b$ \\ \hline
    ALLD (Reject) & 0,0 &  0,0 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation}

As we can see in the Table of (\ref{eq:tab})\dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! (Sorry for the very simple question)